# How much should my dog eat?

Tags: dogs, diet

My dog is 1.5 years old. She is Labrador 30 kg. She is lazy, total walk (not running) per day is 50 min. I saw so many tips on how to feed dogs. Here are three:

1. 20*30 = 600g meat per day. Someone's advice 600+other* = 900 per day
2. 20*30 is total food weight. That means 50% meat, 50% other. 300g meat+300 other.
3. Someone's advice to give less meat if the dog is lazy. That means 200g meat+400 other.

<sub>*Other means buckwheat + vegetables</sub>

What is good for my dog?

Comment: Is she fed raw or kibble? I'm assuming you're talking about home made?

Comment: She eats raw meat. Yes its home made food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This place has a [calculator](https://www.rawpawspetfood.com/serving-size-calculator-s/153.htm) that can give you a basic idea of the ratios based upon weight.  Generally speaking about 2.5% to 3% of the desired weight is what I feed to all my dogs for weight maintenance.  My smallest one is hyperactive and on the skinnier end so she gets 5%.

You should keep in mind you don't have to feed bones and organs every day.  The balanced meals can be once or twice a week.  And I follow the rule of about 5% of the monthly intake being organs and about 8% bones.

These are some other sites to provide more insight as well.
rawfeddogs.org/rawguide.html
primalpooch.com/prey-model-vs-barf/